# List user's account labels using API in Google apps scriipt

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a GAS script to centrally manage labels and filter for my domain's users.

My first goal, create a new label, was reached with this code:

```
function crea_etichetta(nomeEtichetta, currentOwnerEmail) {
  var currentOwnerEmail = "testuser@mydomain.it";
  var service = getService(currentOwnerEmail);
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url= 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'+ currentOwnerEmail +'/labels';
    var payload = {
        name: nomeEtichetta};
    var jpayload = JSON.stringify(payload);
    var options = {method: "post",
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   headers : {
                     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
                   },
                   payload: jpayload,
                   muteHttpExceptions: true
                  };        

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200 || 
        (response.getResponseCode() === 400 && response.getContentText().indexOf('were successfully shared'))
    ) {
      return response.getContentText();
    }
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 401 && response.getContentText().indexOf('Invalid Credentials')) {
      throw 'Unable to transfer ownership from owner ' + currentOwnerEmail + ' ... ' +
        'Please make sure the file\'s owner has a Google Apps license (and not a Google Apps Vault - Former Employee license) and try again.';
    }
    throw response.getContentText(); 
  } else {
    throw service.getLastError();
  }
}

function getService(userEmail) {
  return OAuth2.createService('Gmail:' + userEmail)
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
      .setSubject(userEmail)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic')
      .setScope('https://mail.google.com/')
      ;
}
```

The second goal is to list all labels from a user. Reading the reference manual [Method: users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list?hl=en_GB), I found that "The request body must be empty."

I don't know how to do this! Trying with this code:

```
function listLabel(currentOwnerEmail) {
  var service = getService(currentOwnerEmail);
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'+ currentOwnerEmail + '/labels/';
    var payload = "";
    var jpayload =  JSON.stringify(payload);
  
    var options = {method: "post",
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   headers : {
                     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
                   },
                   payload: jpayload,
                   muteHttpExceptions: true
                  };        

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200 || 
        (response.getResponseCode() === 400 && response.getContentText().indexOf('were successfully shared'))
    ) {
      return response.getContentText();
    }
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 401 && response.getContentText().indexOf('Invalid Credentials')) {
      throw 'Unable to transfer ownership from owner ' + currentOwnerEmail + ' ... ' +
        'Please make sure the file\'s owner has a Google Apps license (and not a Google Apps Vault - Former Employee license) and try again.';
    }
    throw response.getContentText(); 
  } else {
    throw service.getLastError();
  }
}
```

I get this response:

```
> [21-10-21 12:05:33:617 CEST] {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid request",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidArgument"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong in creating a request with empty body, I tried in many ways without results.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `POST` but to retrieve information I have to use `GET`!!

Now it works!